# How to add a row to JTable after populating data using DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, jframe

I have a JTable defined in this way:

```
public JTable table_1;
model_3 = new DefaultTableModel(); 
table_1 = new JTable(model_3);  
scrollPane_5.setViewportView(table_1);
```

Add row:

```
model_3.addRow(new Object[]{table.getValueAt(row,0) , table.getValueAt(row,1) ,table.getValueAt(row,2) , commentFood });
```

Remove Row:

```
model_3.removeRow(row);  //row is an integer
```

Until here, it used to work properly. As you can see this table is defined as public because sometimes I need to fill it up from another JFrame in this way:

```
takeOrder to = new takeOrder();
//Get data from DB to resultSet
to.table_1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(resultSet));
```

If I fill up the table in this way and try to add or remove my `model_3`, it will not work! Any suggestion that how I can add or remove to the table after using `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(resultSet)` will be appreciated.

Comment: Think about this, what relationship does `model_3` have with `JTable#getModel`?  Once you call `setModel`, you change the reference of the object that the table is using for the `TableModel`, which no longer points to `model_3`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer you're right. But is there anyway to add or remove row to the table after setting model to DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(resultSet)?

Comment: It will depend on the type of `TableModel` that `DbUtils`.  Since I have no JavaDocs for that API, I can't say

Answer (score 0):

As I couldn't find any information on the internet and I saw couple of people asked same question with no answer. I came up with this solution:

```
if (formOut) {
    for (int i = 0; i < table_1.getRowCount(); i++) {
        model_3.addRow(new Object[]{table_1.getValueAt(i,0), 
            table_1.getValueAt(i, 1), table_1.getValueAt(i, 2)});
    }
}

formOut = false;
table_1.setModel(model_3);
```

`fromOut` is a boolean to check if I have used another model for my table. If so I add data from table to previous model, and then I reference that model to my table. Now I can add to that model as well.